# Handlebar phone holder on road bike could that cause my camera on google pixel to start taking blurry pictures?

Tags: smartphone-mount

I ride approx  30miles every time I ride my bike,  at least 3 times a week with my phone on a handlebar phone-mount.  This year I have been riding more a week, and I notice my pixel3 phones camera starting to take blurry pictures cannot focus the pictures .   I can  take selfies so its just one side of the phone.

Has anyone had a similar occurrence and is there something I can do ??  I know this is a bicycle forum but  I believe it is caused by the bike rides whether its the vibration or the  sun hitting it and was just wondering if  there is  someone seeing the same thing.

Thank you
Judy

Comment: You're using your phone while actively riding ?   Try stopping and taking the picture while stopped - is it still blurry ?

Comment: I have no idea, but this sounds like the lens or camera have moved, possibly due to vibrations. I think usually smartphones are quite sturdy. I don’t think you can repair it, usually the camera module is one solid brick which can’t be opened (even if you can open the phone). But before you throw it away you should still give it a try.

Comment: I suspect that the vibrations have caused the camera components to come loose internally.

Answer (score 1):

I am 99% sure that the issue is not the bicycle (unless you changed from a soft/wide tyre to a super-skinny one, having too many vibrations that the photo-software cannot compensate adequately).

What you get is resulting from the lens being dirty, so the phone either:

- needs longer exposure, so the bike movement is noticeable (blurry from movement);
- the effective resolution is degraded, so you get images so soft that they look blurry (blurry from diffraction of light);

You can look carefully at the lens. If it looks with a lot of dust and little grains, like this:
[image]
then you have the same issue I had, the second I mentioned, which I discovered it was quite common with some expensive phone from a notorious american brand :( (I cannot say anything for the more recent models or for your phone).

Comment: thank you I will check it out.  and  actually i went from thin tire to  a gravel bike but have only ridden it on the road not gravel yet

Comment: It can be that the tyre profile + different fork /frame makes more vibrations, more than the camera stabilizer can accomodate. 
Please provide two shots of the same scene with front and back camera. 
Anyhow, if it is the vibrations, you can try with gluing some foam/rubber inside the handlebar phone mount, to try dampening the vibrations.

have a look at https://www.androidpolice.com/2019/08/05/the-pixel-3-cant-shake-all-these-user-complaints-of-stuttering-camera-performance/